# Is there a way to get the configuration 'recursively'?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I need to get the default configured database details from Laravel (in an Artisan command).

I'm doing this: `Config::get('database.connections.'.Config::get('database.default').'.username'` which is quite ugly.

Is there a better way, some notation that I am ignorant about?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. Some other ways are getting the entire array and then getting the default from that.

```
$default = Config::get('database.default');
$connections = Config::get('database.connections');

$username = $connections[$default]['username'];
```